# Different partition number when union Spark dataframes with Scala and Python API

Tags: scala, apache-spark, pyspark, union, partition

I am checking the number of the partitions of the union of 2 **identical** Spark dataframes, and I noticed that the result is not the same between Scala and Pyhton API.

With Python the number of the partitions of the union is the sum of the number of partitions of the 2 dataframes which is the expected behavior.

**Python**

```
from pyspark.sql.types import IntegerType

df1 = spark.createDataFrame(range(100000), IntegerType()).repartition(10)
print("df1 partitions: %d" %df1.rdd.getNumPartitions())

df2 = spark.createDataFrame(range(100000), IntegerType()).repartition(10)
print("df2 partitions: %d" %df2.rdd.getNumPartitions())

df3 = df1.union(df2)
print("df3 partitions: %d" %df3.rdd.getNumPartitions())
```

Result:

```
df1 partitions: 10
df2 partitions: 10
df3 partitions: 20
```

However, with scala the number of partitions of the union doesn't change.

**Scala**

```
val df1 = (1 to 100000).toDF.repartition(10)
println(s"df1 partitions: ${df1.rdd.getNumPartitions}")

val df2 = (1 to 100000 by 1).toDF.repartition(10)
println(s"df2 partitions: ${df2.rdd.getNumPartitions}")

val df3 = df1.union(df2)
println(s"df3 partitions: ${df3.rdd.getNumPartitions}")
```

Result:

```
df1 partitions: 10
df2 partitions: 10
df3 partitions: 10
```

This is only when the 2 dataframes are built exacltly in the same way.

When is not:

```
val df1 = (1 to 100000).toDF.repartition(10)
println(s"df1 partitions: ${df1.rdd.getNumPartitions}")

val df2 = (1 to 100000 by 2).toDF.repartition(10)
println(s"df2 partitions: ${df2.rdd.getNumPartitions}")

val df3 = df1.union(df2)
println(s"df3 partitions: ${df3.rdd.getNumPartitions}")
```

I get the expected result (the sum):

```
df1 partitions: 10
df2 partitions: 10
df3 partitions: 20
```

My understanding is that with Scala API Spark is able to optimize the union in some cases. This is true ? and this means that the execution plan of the union could be different between Scala and Python API ?

I am asking the question because I have noticed that the union is more performant with Scala than with Python, especially in the case of muliple unions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The clue is via the explain for Scala engine:

```
Union
:- Exchange RoundRobinPartitioning(10), [id=#757]
:  +- LocalTableScan [value#154]
+- ReusedExchange [value#159], Exchange RoundRobinPartitioning(10), [id=#757]
```

The ReusedExchange is a form of optimization. Catalyst sees they are identical.

If you have one with 10000 and one with 10001 entries, then the 20 partitions are gotten. Spark has some smarts.

Answer (score 3):

Defintion of union in  spark - scala

```
def union(other: Dataset[T]): Dataset[T] = withSetOperator {
    // This breaks caching, but it's usually ok because it addresses a very specific use case:
    // using union to union many files or partitions.
    CombineUnions(Union(logicalPlan, other.logicalPlan))
  }
```

definition of union in pyspark

```
def union(self, other):
        # Return a new :class:`DataFrame` containing union of rows in this and #another
        #:class:`DataFrame`.
        #This is equivalent to `UNION ALL` in SQL. To do a SQL-style set union
        #(that does deduplication of elements), use this function followed by #:func:`distinct`.
        #Also as standard in SQL, this function resolves columns by position (not #by name).

        return DataFrame(self._jdf.union(other._jdf), self.sql_ctx)
```

refer the  code  here to understand the  difference 
https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/sql/catalyst/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/catalyst/optimizer/Optimizer.scala

https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/Dataset.scala

https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/python/pyspark/sql/dataframe.py

Comment: Maybe you can expand your answer beyond a few links with an explanation and narrative. That will make it more valuable to everyone.

Comment: i am trying to figure this out , hopefully will update some more explanation soon

Comment: well i am sharing my observations  , if you see i have clearly mentioned i will update  as in when i find some thing interesting

Comment: your answer is fine Raina, maybe it would be better to merge them together into one in combination with the changes @mazaneicha suggested

Answer (score 1):

Will keep updating if I find anything interesting

**Observation1 --** Physical plans have a difference  between scala and python

```
union physical plan pyspark 
:- Exchange RoundRobinPartitioning(10), [id=#1318]
:  +- *(1) Scan ExistingRDD[value#148]
+- Exchange RoundRobinPartitioning(10), [id=#1320]
   +- *(2) Scan ExistingRDD[value#154]



== Physical Plan scala  ==
Union
:- Exchange RoundRobinPartitioning(10), [id=#1012]
:  +- LocalTableScan [value#122]
+- ReusedExchange [value#131], Exchange RoundRobinPartitioning(10), [id=#1012]


 scala  Range (1 to 10 by 2) == Physical Plan ==
 val df2 = (1 to 10 by 2).toDF.repartition(10)
Union
:- Exchange RoundRobinPartitioning(10), [id=#1644]
:  +- LocalTableScan [value#184]
+- Exchange RoundRobinPartitioning(10), [id=#1646]
   +- LocalTableScan [value#193]
```

**Observation 2** -- union  in spark will not incur a shuffle operation mostly , its a very efficient operation.I believe  its the explicit repartitioning of the df1 and df2 that is causing the number of partitions to vary for the union'ed df3. If you don't explicitly partition your  input `Dataframes` you end up  with a union'ed df with partition number equivalent to the sum of df1 and df2.  I tried following permutations on the same data and got the results under

CASE 1

```
from pyspark.sql.types import IntegerType
  df1 = spark.createDataFrame(range(100000), IntegerType())
  print("df1 partitions: %d" %df1.rdd.getNumPartitions())
  print("df1 partitioner: %s" %df1.rdd.partitioner)
  df2 = spark.createDataFrame(range(100000), IntegerType())
  print("df2 partitions: %d" %df2.rdd.getNumPartitions())
  print("df2 partitioner: %s" %df2.rdd.partitioner)
  df3 = df1.union(df2)
  print("df3 partitions: %d" %df3.rdd.getNumPartitions())
  print("df3 partitioner: %s" %df3.rdd.partitioner)
```

******O/P*******

```
df1 partitions: 8
df1 partitioner: None
df2 partitions: 8
df2 partitioner: None

df3 partitions: 16
df3 partitioner: None
```

CASE 2

```
val df1 = (1 to 100000).toDF
println(s"df1 partitions: ${df1.rdd.getNumPartitions}")
println(s"df1 partitioner: ${df1.rdd.partitioner}")
val df2 = (1 to 100000).toDF

println(s"df2 partitions: ${df2.rdd.getNumPartitions}")
println(s"df2 partitioner: ${df2.rdd.partitioner}")
 df1.union(df2).explain()
val df3 = df1.union(df2)

println(s"df3 partitions: ${df3.rdd.getNumPartitions}")
println(s"df3 partitioner: ${df3.rdd.partitioner}")
```

******O/P*******

```
df1 partitions: 8
df1 partitioner: None
df2 partitions: 8
df2 partitioner: None
df3 partitions: 16
df3 partitioner: None
```

CASE 3

```
val df1 = (1 to 100000).toDF
println(s"df1 partitions: ${df1.rdd.getNumPartitions}")
println(s"df1 partitioner: ${df1.rdd.partitioner}")
val df2 = (1 to 100000 by 2).toDF
println(s"df2 partitions: ${df2.rdd.getNumPartitions}")
println(s"df2 partitioner: ${df2.rdd.partitioner}")
val df3 = df1.union(df2)
println(s"df3 partitions: ${df3.rdd.getNumPartitions}")
println(s"df3 partitioner: ${df3.rdd.partitioner}")
```

****O/P****

```
df1 partitions: 8
df1 partitioner: None
df2 partitions: 8
df2 partitioner: None
df3 partitions: 16
df3 partitioner: None
```